# Ansible to create aws security group and add to instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am creating an EC2 instance. My creation flow is,

1. Create Ami
2. Create security group
3. Create new Instance from AMI and add to security group

My new security group should only contain private ip of a new instance with appropriate ports open

My concern is, How can I create security group and add EC2 Instance private IP if that instance is yet to be created

Is there any way that I can wait for the Instance creation task first and after it is done I fetch the private IP and use that in above task which is "Security group Creation"?

If you have any suggestions please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that I can wait for the Instance creation task first and after it is done I fetch the private IP and use that in above task which is "Security group Creation"?

Sure, that's exactly what [`ec2:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/ec2_module.html) (or the newer [`ec2_instance:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/ec2_instance_module.html)) will do when given the `wait: yes` argument. By using `register: ec2_result` you can then use `ec2_result.instances[0].private_ip_address` (as seen [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.1/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_instance.py#L536)) inside the [`ec2_group:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/ec2_group_module.html) module to define the rules for the SG.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need to first create an instance, fetch private ip and add it to SG group which can be done by your answer.
whereas I also need to attach that SG to an AWS Instance,
In short my flow is, 

1. Create instance

2. Create SG

3. Add Private Ip of Instance to SG

4. Add SG to that Instance again

Comment: Ok, great; I am about 90% certain that one `- ec2: wait=yes` followed by `- ec2_group:` followed by a second `- ec2: instance_ids: ... security_groups: {{ existing_sg + new_sg_id }}` will do what you described